# Recursive import of components using webpack in React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Each time I have to import a Component, I can either use its absolute path :

```
import ProductDescription from '../../ProductDescription';
```

or define an alias in my `webpack.config.js` file :

```
alias: {
    app: 'components/app',
    home: 'components/home',
    utility: 'components/common/utility',
    textService: 'services/textService'
},
```

So that I can import like this :

```
import Home from 'home';
import Utility from 'utility';
```

Now obviously, both work fine, but both are shite. Is there a way to recursively configure my webpack so that it resolves all files within my `/src` directory ?

I've tried using the  `modules` option like this :

```
modules: ['node_modules', 'src', paths.appNodeModules]
```

But this failed miserably.

Comment: It gets much worse with typescript - adding an alias to webpack is not discovered by typescript unless you also create a definition file with the same. Be happy with what you have :)  -- an aside: generally in larger apps you'll have an `index.js` file in every directory which exports a set of components from it's own folder. Create aliases to these indexes and it's pretty slick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

**In webpack config**

```
alias: {
  components: 'components', // base path to components
},
```

**In your code**

```
import Header from 'components/header'
import Footer from 'component/footer'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's about exactly the way I used the aliases in my examples :D

Comment: No, you declare the alias once and import components relative to the alias. You won't be changing the alias for every new import. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `src` folder you should have the structure similar to this:

```
src
└ scenes
  ├ components
  │ ├ ComponentA
  │ │ └ ComponentA.jsx
  │ └ ComponentB
  │   └ ComponentB.jsx
  └ main
    ├ components
    │ └ App
    │   ├ components
    │   │ ├ ComponentC
    │   │ │ └ ComponentC.jsx
    │   │ └ ComponentD
    │   │   └ ComponentD.jsx
    │   └ App.jsx
    └ index.jsx
```

In your `webpack.config.js` you should have the following (Webpack 3):

```
const DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin = require('directory-named-webpack-plugin');
...
let config = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
      modules: ['components', 'node_modules'],
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
      plugins: [
          new DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin(true)
      ]
  }
  ...
}
modules.exports = config;
```

As a result of using the above configuration and folder structure webpack will search for components in `components` folders recursively in the same way it searches for Node modules in `node_modules` folder and you can include components by their names.
E. g. in `src/scenes/main/index.jsx` you can simply write:

```
import App from 'App';
```

in `src/scenes/main/components/App/App.jsx` you can write:

```
import ComponentC from 'ComponentC';
import ComponentD from 'ComponentD';
```

and in `src/scenes/main/components/App/components/CompoentC/ComponentC.jsx` you can write:

```
import ComponentA from 'ComponentA';
import ComponentB from 'ComponentB';
```

**P. S.**
I use the plugin [directory-named-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/directory-named-webpack-plugin) to allow webpack to recognize files named after their parent folders as default entry points for components so in my IDE tabs' names I would not see `ComponentA/index.jsx`, `ComponentB/index.jsx` and instead see `ComponentA.jsx`, `ComponentB.jsx`.