# How to import index.vue by just mentioning the parent directory name rather than filename?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I've been building my Vue application by using Vue Cli 3.

If I need to import an `index.js` which is in directory named `Dir1`, I can import it using 
`import file1 from '@/components/Dir1/` 
but somehow it doesn't work with `.vue` extension files.

I have to expicitly mention the file name such as `import Title from @/components/Title/index.vue`.

What changes do I have to make in the settings in order to import the `.vue` extension file without mentioning the filename?

Comment: This works just fine for me. Can you provide some more context, or a repo with your problem?

Comment: Post your `webpack` configuration

Comment: Did you get your problem resolved? I have the same issue and can't seem to find the solution. My project is initialized with Vue's CLI 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it with Vue.

You may need to tweak the config a little bit to suit your dev environment needs.
Note that this is not a full config but a guideline on what should be done based on [NPM directory-named-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/directory-named-webpack-plugin) documentation.

In your webpack.config.js you should have the following (Webpack 3):

```
const DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin = require('directory-named-webpack-plugin');
// ...
let config = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['components', 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
    plugins: [
      new DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin(true)
    ]
  }
  // ...
}
modules.exports = config;
```

taken and modified for Vue from: [Recursive import of components using webpack in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929401/recursive-import-of-components-using-webpack-in-react)

Comment: how about Vite?